# ruby error: application.rb:6:in `require': cannot load such file -- active_job/railtie (LoadError)

Tags: debian, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Суть проблемы:

> $rails generate rspec:install
>   /home/darkfox/Study/sample_app/config/application.rb:6:in require:
>   cannot load such file -- active_job/railtie (LoadError)
>    from /home/darkfox/Study/sample_app/config/application.rb:6:in    from
>   /home/darkfox/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p645/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:43:in require
>   from /home/darkfox/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p645/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:43:in
>     from bin/rails:8:in require from bin/rails:8:in

В качестве руководства к действию использовался учебник на railstutorial.ru. До 3 главы проблем не было. Операционная система debian.
Версия ruby:

> ruby -v
>   ruby 2.0.0p645 (2015-04-13 revision 50299) [i686-linux]
>   Версия rails:
>   rails -v
>   Rails 4.0.2
>   OS:
>   uname -a
>   Linux 3.16.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt11-1
>   (2015-05-24) i686 GNU/Linux

Gemfile:

```html
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.0.2'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

Если перешагнуть этот шаг руководства и приступить к следующему, то данная проблема возникает снова уже на:

> rails generate controller StaticPages home help --no-test-framework

Установку rvm проводил следующим образом:

> $ curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s
>   Затем зависимости для установки ruby и собственно:
>    rvm install 2.0.0 --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr
>   То есть никакой отсебятины не лепил, делал все по шагам как указано в учебнике.

Кто сталкивался, подскажите пожалуйста в чем подвох.

Comment: Попробуйте переустановить rails. Насколько понимаю, этот файл включен в стандартный пакет rails, и, похоже, стандартный пакет просто побился.

Comment: rvm uninstall all; rvm implode; после повторил все процедуру установки заново. Безрезультатно, проблема та же =(

Comment: Интересные дела. ActiveJob -- новинка в Rails 4.2, в 4.0.2 его и в помине не было. Что у вас в `application.rb`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как я понял, вы просто создали проект на rails > 4.2 и попытались изменить гемфайл с существующим application.rb, в котором описана зависимость ActiveJob, существующая на rails 4.2, но не существующая на rails 4.0.2, я думаю не стоит описывать свой гемфайл как в туториале, а делать с существующим, либо создать новый проект сразу на rails 4.0.2